# Where does Squirrel SQL store its auto correct entries?

Tags: java, db2, squirrel-sql

I use Squirrel SQL as my goto SQL editor for DB2 for iSeries, and one feature I love is the autocorrect. I enter shortcuts into the editor like ssf and "select * from" pops up.

I know it's possible to add entries to the library one row at a time, but how can I add multiple entries at once? I understand it could be an in-depth editing of resource files, and I'm comfortable enough with Java to make the edit but not find the actual resource.

The bookmarks feature doesn't suit my needs for this, and it still wouldn't allow me to enter the 140+ autocorrections I want to add.

Comment: Consider change to Where does Squirrel store the auto correct shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it--after digging through the class files, I found the file they referred to an xml stored at .squirrel-sql\plugins\syntax\autocorrectdata.xml

That saves a ton of time. Now I can type a table name and it will auto-populate the table schema, table name, and the preferred correlation.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Squirrel-SQL that store user-defined autocorrect data in local user folders, see [Where is the Syntax-Autocorrect data stored in Squirrel-SQL snapshot 20190612_2127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291233)