# Where is the Syntax-Autocorrect data stored in Squirrel-SQL snapshot 20190612_2127?

Tags: squirrel-sql, autocorrect

In older versions of Squirrel-SQL, autocorrect data was stored in an XML file as documented in [Where does Squirrel SQL store its auto correct entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744907). After updating to a more recent version, this file no longer exists in the same "syntax" folder (C:\Program Files\SQuirreL SQL Client\plugins\syntax). Does anyone know where I might be able to locate this file?

Since there wasn't much to work with in the old "syntax" folder, I dug into the syntax.jar file in the "plugins" parent folder and found a bunch of .class files in the zipped folder "syntax\net\sourceforge\squirrel_sql\plugins\syntax" (peaking into the .jar file as it were). There were a few files that looked promising, such as

```
AutoCorrectData.class
AutoCorrectDataItem.class
AutoCorrectProviderImpl.class
```

But none of them contained autocorrect entries I have added to the client - although the last .class file listed above references an "autocorrectdata.xml" file, which is what I could not find in the first place.

Any help I can get on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Turns out newer versions of Squirrel-SQL store user-defined autocorrect data in local user folders. Makes a lot of sense actually! Found my autocorrectdata.xml file in the following folder:

C:\Users\[My Username]\.squirrel-sql\plugins\syntax